# PHP check to make sure request is either xmlhttp from my site or normal request from a certain domain

Tags: php, logic

How would the condition be written to ensure a page is either accessed by xmlhttp request from my site or from an allowed outside domain?

```
<?php
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] !== 'XMLHttpRequest') {
        if(preg_match("/accepteddomain.com/",$referrer) {
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com/desiredpage.php");
        } else {
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com/nondesiredpage.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're going to run into problems if any of your users are behind a Proxy, Firewall, or Anonymizer service that doesn't included Referrer information.

Comment: It is a business partner of ours, who is behind neither and doesn't use a web proxy. I'm past the dont's and need to find out the do's

Comment: Check the values of your `$_SERVER` array, you might have overlooked something.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that both Referer and X-Request-With headers are sent *(or not sent)* by the client *(the browser, or anything else that can send an HTTP request)*, they cannot be trusted.

You can use those as hints, to enhance user-experience ; but you must not rely on them to be either present or correct.

Basically, you have no way to be sure that a request comes from a specific domain *(even for XmlHttpRequest : the browser can only use XHR on the same domain... But you have no way to be sure that a request you receive is, or is not, coming from XHR)*.

Amongst possible ideas *(not sure what your real problem / need is)*, you might try using some kind of API-key, to limit request-rates or so ?

Comment: Great point! Never trust input from the client. All security logic/verification steps that are critical to the operation being performed should be handled by the server.

Comment: I realize that it's not bulletproof. Its just a simple mechanism to deter most people from accessing my forms directly. It just so happens theres one form that needs to be accessed by ONE client. is it possible? the syntax is getting errors

Comment: @Dirty Bird You really have nothing to worry about if the call is an XMLHHTPRequst. You should only be worried that other scripts can call your page.

Comment: Look, i have a boss that insists the page can't be accessed directly. so I bring in a section of it with jquery .ajax. I check for a session id to make sure you can't access it directly. Now somebody has to be able to access it directly. So here I am, a designer/front end guy trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You spelt referrer correctly but unfortunately the person who wrote the HTTP spec couldn't! You need to use `HTTP_REFERER`.

You might also want to escape the dot `\.` so it only matches a dot and not everything.

Comment: so I spelled something right, but someone else spelled it wrong? thats a first.

Comment: by dot you mean domain\.\com?

Comment: man no matter what I do, it redirects me to the "not allowed page"

Comment: Have you output your $_SERVER array to see what's in it? print_r($_SERVER);

Comment: @Ewan - it returns a lot of stuff, is there something specific I need to look for?

Comment: The two values you're using in your `if()` statement.

Comment: Check that the HTTP_REFERER and HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH elements are present and contain what you expected

Comment: Are you entering the page using the URL directly or via a link on another page?

Comment: I have a link set up on the "allowddomain.com/pagewithlink.php" page that needs to have access to "http://www.domain.com/desiredpage.php"

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are only possible from the same domain. You cannot make an XMLHttp request from another site due to inbuilt security reasons.

This site outlines states perfectly that you cannot launch a cross-domain XMLHTTPRequest
http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

All modern web browsers impose a security restriction on network connections, which includes calls to XMLHttpRequest. This restriction prevents a script or application from making a connection to any web server other than the one the web page originally came from (Internet Explorer will allow cross-domain requests if the option has been enabled in the preferences). If both your web application and the XML data that application uses come directly from the same server, then you do not run into this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that HTTP headers are easily spoofed so someone could easily telnet and send that HTTP header and access the page. Do not rely upon HTTP REFERER for sensitive data. The only reasonably safe prevention is to use logins.