# PHP redirect if not specific HTTP_REFERRER or an xmlHttp request

Tags: php, http, redirect, logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP check to make sure request is either xmlhttp from my site or normal request from a certain domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252077/php-check-to-make-sure-request-is-either-xmlhttp-from-my-site-or-normal-request-f)

not sure why this doesn't work, it keeps redirecting me to the  //not allowed page. I need to make this page accessible ONLY via an ajax request or a link from a specified domain(s). I've tried putting this in the head of the page I'm trying to get to as well as in a separate script and pointing a link from the allowed domain to the script.

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/alloweddomain.com\/pagewithlink.php/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'])    || 
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
// allowed
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/desiredpage.php');
} else {
// not allowed
header('Location: http://www.cnn.com');
}
?>
```