# Is it possible to allow traffic from only one site to a page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been banging my head against this for a week. I have a page that we want to only be accessible from another domain. Is it possible with PHP or .htaccess? Ive posted a couple attempts to do this on here, nothing seems to work. Please help!

```
<?php

$allowed_domains = array('dirtybirddesignlab.com','foo.com');

$REFERRER = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if ($REFERRER == '') {
    exit(header('Location: 404.php'));
}

$domain = substr($REFERRER, strpos($REFERRER, '://')+3);
$domain = substr($domain, 0, strpos($domain, '/'));

if (!in_array($domain, $allowed_domains)) {
    exit(header('Location:404.php'));
}

?>
```

Comment: Your question is confused. Accesses don't come from domains, they come from IP addresses.

Comment: Previous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252077/php-check-to-make-sure-request-is-either-xmlhttp-from-my-site-or-normal-request-f

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question over and over? Stick with the original question.

Comment: Previous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254070/php-redirect-if-not-specific-http-referrer-or-an-xmlhttp-request

Comment: Because Im not getting anywhere asking the specific question, so I stepped back and made it more general. My apologies to all of you.

Comment: I'm actually getting some good knowledge, no need to close. thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on my comment, see the line `if ($REFERRER == '')` block.

```
<?php

$allowed_domains = array('mydomain.com','yourdomain.com');

$REFERRER = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if ($REFERRER == '') {
    // What do you do here?
}

$domain = substr($REFERRER, strpos($REFERRER, '://')+3);
$domain = substr($domain, 0, strpos($domain, '/'));

if (!in_array($domain, $allowed_domains)) {
    exit(header('Location: error.php'));
}

?>
```

Note, the above will fall through to always referring those browsers that haven't reported a referrer to be redirected to the error.php page.

My suggestion is to do something like...

1. Generate salt, share with other server ($dsalt = output from something like [puttygen.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html))
2. Generate shared key on the other domain during response - $dkey = sha1($dsalt.date('mDY G'))
3. Put $dkey within page for requests, resulting in "http://www.mydomain.com/getstuff-ajax.php?key=$dkey"
4. Recreate the same $dkey on your server and compare against the one in the GET to detect non-allowed access

For instance...

**Their domain**

```
<?php

$dsalt = "AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBNnuGAM6ZKURAS9h9ag".
         "H85T1eIE+jlLkq7GhFny8wMJNpSM0stTDWeEYfL+4xWIE".
         "lIF3NFvRpDAG/cgXuVmlBcO0ZxxKosrDv0dXCXNt5ciPJ".
         "UjFi1e0FEJtkO32xrTDEB2IUg9rZ0tiqqsqnTCZBQ4AEvpMi";

$dkey = sha1($dsalt.date('mDY G'));

// ... Other stuff or whatnot, possible the above is also just an include file

// Then, they use it...

echo "<a href=\"http://yourdomain.com/download.php?key=$dkey\">Download stuff</a>";

?>
```

**Your domain - include('/path/to/domaincheck.php')**

```
<?php

$dkey = $_GET['key'];

$dsalt = "AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBNnuGAM6ZKURAS9h9ag".
         "H85T1eIE+jlLkq7GhFny8wMJNpSM0stTDWeEYfL+4xWIE".
         "lIF3NFvRpDAG/cgXuVmlBcO0ZxxKosrDv0dXCXNt5ciPJ".
         "UjFi1e0FEJtkO32xrTDEB2IUg9rZ0tiqqsqnTCZBQ4AEvpMi";

if (sha1($dsalt.date('mDY G')) != $dkey) {
    exit(header('Location: error.php'));
}

?>
```

Notice both the $dsalts are the same. I generated that with puttgen.exe.

Something along those lines. You will need to handle cases in which the key may expire, or whatnot. Another method may be to share valid $dkey's between your servers with a timestamp and expire them after a certain amount of time (maybe one hour).

**theirserver.com and yourserver.com**

1. Salt, or in other words, private key, same on both servers
2. Function to (re)create the hash using the salt and some date stamp, same on both servers

**Browser**

1. Links to yourserver.com includes generated key (hash) created from static salt and date stamp function

Comment: @Jared - that is exactly what I needed, both parts. I see now how to do it the right way. It will take some time for me to do it right, but I can manage it. I really appreciate it. I do have a couple questions though, and believe me they are dumb.I know salt is an encryption, is it a fixed value or do they reproduce each time a connection is made relying on the same "generator" on my site and theirs? When you say "Put $dkey in page" it obviously won't be the password, but the var from the script?

Comment: A salt is just a series of text that together consists of a key (in this case, a shared private key) that you use create another hash in which you insert a timestamped piece of information (so that the hash, not salt, is only good for a period of time, by the hour, day, minute, etc...). Technically, it's not encryption, since it's one-way. All you're trying to do is create a hashed value that is too difficult for a third party to construct, while being easy enough for you to recreate accurately and check in comparison for equality.

Comment: So, $dsalt is the same on both servers (I use puttgeny.exe to create unique salt values). Once you create the salted date hash, you then add that within your html you send to the browser, and include it with your requests to the other browser as an 'authorization' check.

Comment: OK, i need to do some reading. I don't get how I create it, the other site sends it and they match

Comment: Share the salt with them and the process to create the salt (which hashes it against a date stamp). Then, on your server add in some code to check the included key in the URL. For it to work, they need to include the hash in the request, typically through the URL, meaning it needs to be within the browser's markup/code, not just the server.

Comment: I added a little description. The salt doesn't have to change, it just needs to be generated and shared with the other server. The function to create the key (hash) needs to be the same on both servers (as does the salt). The key (hash) then needs to be sent to the browser through the page, which then makes any request to your site with the included key (hash) value for you to check.

Comment: ahh ok, so the PHP with $dkey isn't on a page it's a separate file and thats what the other site links to? once it compares the salt, then it redirects accordingly?

Comment: Or you could just create a domaincheck.php file and add `include('/path/to/domaincheck.php');` to the top of the pages you want to protect. I don't know you need a redirect, per se, just for the code to run first thing.

Comment: The exit(header()) takes care of the error and kills the rest of the scripts that follow after. You may also just output the results of another file using another include, or put your error markup directly into the exit() function within domaincheck.php.

Comment: OK, domaincheck sounds do-able, but when searching google all it comes up with are stupid scripts to check if a domain is available. man this could save my ass/job/family etc

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. domaincheck.php would be a file on your server containing the domain check script (as I have in the answer), that you simply include at the top of the pages you want to protect. What you do when you detect a request is not authorized can vary, but domaincheck.php is just a local script on your server.

Comment: ok sorry for misunderstanding. I have it at the top of the page I want protected, unfortunately the domain I have set up the link on doesn't seem to be sending a referrer, as it executes the (header(Location....)); I have in the if $(REFERRER == '' field

Comment: I include it like this: <?php include("domaincheck.php");?> above my <HTML> tag and get errors that it failed to open the stream

Comment: Are you trying to use the referrer method, or the dkey method? They're not interchangeable. Also, the path to the include file needs to point to the file on your server.

Comment: I am trying to use the referrer method for now, Ill have to get more time to do the dkey method, I would have a couple hours of reading just to get it set up. I had it in the same directory as the protected file, now I just get a "Problem loading page" msg

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the top of the protected page, and what's in your domaincheck.php file? If it's in the same directory, it should work, unless you don't have an error.php file setup, too.

Comment: Jared, I hate to even ask, but I've got access to multiple domains, the one with the protected file and another server. I'm going to give the $dkey a shot and see what happens. man if you were in denver i'd buy you a steak and beer

Comment: If I were in Denver, I'd take you up on it. :)

Comment: is there something special about 'error.php' can I just send it to my 404 page?

Comment: No, there's nothing special, except that what header() points to exists on the path. Use your 404 page, or exit('html stuff'), or whatever. It's just a response, in this case a redirect.

Comment: ok so I have the "$dkey" exactly like you have it in a page and i get a 500 error

Comment: If you're using the referrer method, don't fool with the $dkey method - the other server needs to be setup to work with the $dkey and the client needs to be configured to send it with it's requests. So it can't only be on your end, it needs to be setup on their server too.

Comment: Although, I don't know why you'd get a 500 error from the code itself - it's not doing anything special, unless you're not pointing to the 404 page correctly or something. The code is pretty simple.

Comment: f**ck i was going for the dkey. I was hoping they could just use .get to load it into the page and the link would work. man im tired and being dumb. the referrer method is just the PHP script you said is not 100% reliable at the top of your answer. Just put that in a file, fill in the url's and point an external link to it right?

Comment: It should work that way, yes. Can you post your actual referrer code in your question? It'd help a lot of I can see what you're actually using.

Comment: ok posted the code. I have it in a separate file, I point the external link to that file... but I don't see how it gets to the protected page

Comment: that can't be right.. I need that code at the top of my protected page right?

Comment: denton huh? i grew up in lbk. off the subject

Comment: I edited the script to test it and it still works; here is my test page (I'm using a URL variable instead of REFERRER): http://jfcoder.com/test/test.php?domain=http://mydomain.com/hello.php

Comment: Are you saying you're pointing the external file to domaincheck.php? I don't think you need to do that. You can just put it at the top of your php file you're trying to protect (in the form of an include function call).

Comment: no more domaincheck.php file I just have exactly what I posted in the edited question at the top of my protected page

Comment: Yes - it also needs to be a PHP page, parsing PHP. Would you mind letting me look at the actual links?

Comment: I don't know it's a problem, but you might put a space between Location: 404.php in the second exit(). Probably won't fix it, but you never know. What is it currently doing?

Comment: Also, if you're using subdomains (www.mydomain.com, site.subdomain.com, etc...), you need them in your $allowed_domains array, too.

Comment: And, make sure you completely undid any htaccess stuff you may have tried.

Comment: man i dont know wtf - in the line if($REFERRER = '') { exit(header(Location: http://www.mysite/protectedpage.php')); when I put in any other page it works fine, when I put in the one I want protected I get a "Problem Loading page" error

Comment: No its a FireFox page that's gray with error msg in the middle

Comment: exit(header('Location: mysite/protectedpage.php';)); <- That needs to be 404.php page.

Comment: You might be creating an infinite loop, wherein when the domain is not in the list, you're forwarding it right back to the protectedpage.php, which then checks again, which then forwards it back to the protectedpage.php, etc... Both of the exit's need to point to the 404 page, preferably with a fully qualified URL like http://mysite.com/404.php

Comment: I'm going to need to head to bed. You're probably better off sleeping on it and trying again tomorrow. It's not doing any complicated, but if your brain is fried, it won't make sense.

Comment: ok so both exits point to the 404. the file "domaincheck.php" is included like this "<?php include("domaincheck.php");?>" in the first line of my protected page

Comment: man I really appreciate it. Ill either get it or start looking for a new job tomorrow.

Comment: What you posted above should work, given the Location:404.php space "issue", the caveat about matching subdomains for the domains listed, and the placement of the script itself (at the head of your content request chain, preferably at the top of the page requested), it should work just fine. Take a break and look at it with fresh eyes.

Comment: The referrer method is inherently messy, since it relies on the browser. Could be your browser is not reporting the referrer. Create a test page on your server and paste into it <?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER); ?> and see if you are sending an HTTP_REFERER to the server. Note echo and print_r should probably be on separate lines in your test page.

Comment: Location: 404.php instead of Location:404.php. It's probably not an issue (my server works either way), but it looks weird to me. Just to be sure, though...

Comment: Oh, also, on your test page, referrer requires you to link-into the page for the referrer to be set in the $_SERVER variable. So create a page with a link to your test page and then click on that link - that way a HTTP_REFERER shows up. Otherwise, there is no referrer to report.

Comment: For instance, try this page again (I have it set back to HTTP_REFERER): http://jfcoder.com/test/test.php

Comment: That would be, click on it from this page into that link. But, if you copy the link to a new tab, it doesn't show the referrer.

Comment: No referrer, don't even see one on your page

Comment: Yeah, referrers are unreliable. My guess is you may end up with a lot error reports - "I'm doing it right, but it doesn't work" kind've things. Sleep on it though and revisit later. I'm also going to head out now, too.

Comment: FF doesn't send referrers, but Opera does

Comment: @Jared - Wanted to thank you again for the help. I couldn't get it to work as desired but left it as is. If  you ever have time and want to take a look, let me know and I could email the files. thx again. Kane

Comment: Email me; you can find my email address by Googling my name and going to my work website.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
$allowed = array("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
$ip = $REMOTE_ADDR;
if(!in_array($ip, $allowed))
{
header("Location: index.php"); 
exit;
}
?>
```

Replace xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with the ip address of the site?

It will check IP address of traffic and if it's not in the array will redirect them elsewhere as defined in header location

Based on checking if the refferer is from a certain page try this:

```
<?php
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$referer_parse = parse_url($referer);

if($referer_parse['host'] == "mysite.com" || $referer_parse['host'] == "www.mysite.com") {
     // download...
} else {
     header("Location: http://www.mysite.com");
     exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Um, you're checking against the IP of the client. I believe the OP wants a check against the referrer.

Comment: I understand that now with these additional comments however the question originally asked this is a possible solution. 
Been that it's another 'domain' access it one can assume it's going to have an ip and is another server etc so ip filtering could work?

Comment: On a partner's website, there will be a page with a link to our page. I want to make it so you can only get to that page from the partners site > page > link. If someone else just typed it in a browser it would redirect.

Comment: I've updated it now. set mysite.com to the site that should link to you

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design - HTTP_REFERER is not reliable for what you are trying to accomplish, so you need to use another method. I suggest you use a hash algorithm such as SHA1 on a shared salt between you and the server, and then salt that token with something like the date or something. That unique key is something they can generate on their server, include in the page and requests from the page, then read on your server (through a GET parameter).

Comment: @Braddles One question: if the page they are to have access to is "download.php" and I put that in the first if (where it says //download) then place the code on the actual "download.php" will it not loop?

Comment: @Jared - I am not familiar with that. I don't know if I can figure this out by tomorrow.... deadlines

Comment: I just wanted to echo what Jared is saying, that HTTP_REFERER is not good solution for information you want secure. The referer is set by the browser and can be faked with tools like curl and python's urllib.

Comment: I know this. Even if this is basic, it's about all I can do before tomorrow. I'm not a developer, but a designer who knows a little PHP and all we have. just trying to do the best I can and appreciate the help. Although with everything I've tried I keep getting the page in a loop

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design - I expanded on my comment in an answer, including a working piece of code that should work just fine (except in the case the referrer was not provided).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with .htaccess.

order allow,deny
deny from all
Allow from "domain to allow without www"

if domain name doesn't work, try
Allow from "IP address"

Exclude "" in the actual file.

Comment: I get a 403 from the allowed domain. frustrating

Comment: close, can't switch the order, needs to be deny, allow - deny from all then allow, but works!